# Classification of complex projective algebraic varieties of dimension $ n $.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology

Is it possible to classify up to isomorphism all complex projective algebraic varieties of dimension $ n $, like we do for exemple, for topological compact surfaces in elemetary algebraic topology, in order to compute all homological or cohomological groupes of the form : $ H_k ( X , \mathbb{C} ) $ and $ H^k ( X, \mathbb{C} ) $ in a finite way such that $ X $ is a complex projective algebraic variety ? If it is, how to proceed ?

Have you any reference talking about this subject ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The classification of projective varieties is a far-reaching problem, already in dimensions $2$  and $3$, and will probably never be completed. What do you mean by "classify homomorphically"?

Comment: To quote Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry: "In any branch of mathematics, there are usually guiding problems, which are so difficult that one never expect to solve them completely, yet which provide stimulus for a great amount of work, and which serve as yardsticks for measuring progress in the field. In algebraic geometry such a problem is the classification problem. In its strongest form, the problem is to classify all algebraic varieties up to isomorphism." To me, that sounds like the answer to your question is "No, and we probably never will, but we try as hard as we can nonetheless."

Comment: @HeinrichD : Sorry, i mean : homeomorphically.  :-)
.

Comment: So you actually mean a classification of their underlying topological spaces? Really? Or do you mean the classification of the corresponding complex manifolds (in the smooth case)? Please edit the question and make it precise.

Comment: @HeinrichD : It's done. Sorry. :-)

Comment: @Arthur : Where mathematical research stops in this field ? Are there major advances in this area ?

Comment: It is a field of very active research, and it's steadily advancing. It's just that the total classification problem is insanely difficult.

Comment: @YoYo: Your question is unclear because you have not specified what you mean by "isomorphism."  Do you mean "homeomorphism" or "diffeomorphism" or "birationally equivalent" or "isomorphic as projective varieties" or what?  The answer depends heavily on which one you mean.  It sounds to me like your questions are: (1) What homeomorphism types of complex projective varieties are possible, and (2) Given a complex projective variety, how does one compute its singular homology and cohomology groups? But maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @YoYo a question of current research is whether there is an infinite number of calabi yau 3 folds. that being said, your question is WAY too optimistic. Jesse I think he is asking whether cohomology can be used to classify varieties.

Comment: @Rüdiger : I'm asking whether classifing all complex projective algebraic varieties of dimension $ n $ can be used to compute groups of homology and cohomology of all complex projective algebraic varieties ?

Comment: @Jesse : ''isomorphism'' = ''homeomorphism'', i actually mean a classification of their underlying topological spaces.

Comment: @YoYo : I assume that by the underlying topological space of a complex projective variety you mean the underlying *analytic* topology, since you seem to be interested in singular cohomology. If not, I suppose it's worth mentioning that in his thesis, Mel Hochster identifed precisely those topological spaces (in terms of point-set topological properties) which arise as the spectrum of a commutative ring with unit.